# .htaccess 404 redirect not working correctly

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I recently transferred my website to another domain. I have the old domain redirecting old links to the splash page. Although because I used wordpress the previous links such as - http://scottramsay.co/services/multi-track-mixing-mastering/ I get a css error.

The redirect works when there is not a second backslash, although when a second the redirect does not read the css file.

Example:

Works correctly - scottramsay.co/services

Does not work - scottramsay.co/services/multi-track-mixing-mastering/

How would I fix this? I'm guessing it's something to do with the .htaccess file.

**.htaccess code currently:**
    ErrorDocument    404    /

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a more fundamental issue in the coding.  Looking at the pages side by side they both attempt to load CSS & JavaScript from './' which basically means 'this directory.' But it can only be in one place.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./enter.css" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./enter.js"></script>
```

Without seeing the full `.htaccess` I would recommend you just create full URLs for those items as shown below. Especially if this is a WordPress site that can set base/root URLs easilly.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://scottramsay.co/enter.css" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scottramsay.co/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scottramsay.co/enter.js"></script>
```